# VBA- Extracting Paragraph from Section in IE

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, vba

I want to extract text from each section of Article from this link :

http://iuhealth.org/search/results/global/Memorial%20Sloan%20Kettering%20Cancer%20Center/P1/

```
    Slink = "http://iuhealth.org/search/results/global/Memorial%20Sloan%20Kettering%20Cancer%20Center/P1/"
With httpRequest
    .Open "GET", Slink, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send
End With
With httpRequest
    While Not .readyState = 4
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
    Wend
    If .Status = 200 Then
        While InStr(1, .responseText, "Updating", 0) > 0
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
        Wend
        Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument
        oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End If
End With

ReDim title(0)
ReDim LinkS(0)
ReDim Spec(0)

Set aelem = oHtml.getElementsByTagName("article")
MsgBox aelem.Length
For Each ele In aelem

Next ele
```

I am able to get Header i.e. "Stephen D. Beck, MD | Find a Doctor | IU Health"
but not the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the web testing framework Selenium and there is a VBA wrapper written for it.
Read https://codingislove.com/browser-automation-in-excel-selenium/.

One tip from my experience: If you are using Chrome, after you install SeleniumBasic from https://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/, you will need to replace C:\Users\your_Windows_ID\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic\chromedriver.exe with the latest chromedriver.exe from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

Comment: No Cbasah. I am still not able to find the solution from addins.